# How can I use the "WHERE" clause in MDX or its equivalent?

Tags: visual-studio, sass, mdx

im' working with analysis services. I need to perform a calculation and for this i use kpi. In the field "value expression" from KPI i establishid the calculation with an expression MDX. Works fine but i don't know how put the clause "WHERE" in the query o how use it

```
(([Measures].[Recuento Factonlymatriculacion],[Dimmatriculacion].[Nivel].&[Universitario])*100)/([Measures].[Recuento Factsolicitud],[Dimplan].[Nivel].&[Universitario]))
WHERE 
([Measures].[Recuento Factsolicitud],[Dimaniosolicitud].[Anio])  IS ([Measures].[Recuento Factmatriculacion],[Dimmatriculacion].[Anio])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `WHERE`. Just form a two part tuple, with Anio as the second part:

```
(
DIVIDE(
    ([Measures].[Recuento Factonlymatriculacion],[Dimmatriculacion].[Nivel].&[Universitario] * 100), 
    [Measures].[Recuento Factsolicitud],[Dimplan].[Nivel].&[Universitario]
)
, [Measures].[Recuento Factmatriculacion],[Dimmatriculacion].[Anio]
)
```

But there looks to be an issue as `Anio` is part of `Measures` so I don't understand how your original logic will return anything other than blank?